# PL/SQL exception ORA-06511 cursor already open

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Lately we are seeing the following error in our application log, this happens only sometimes (once in a week or so), leading us to believe that the cursor exception is thrown only by some specific input condition/unhandled exception.

> Error - SQL state [24000]; error code [6511]; ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open
>   ORA-06512: at "PACKAGE", **line 3**
>   ORA-06512: at "APPS.TLN_AR_ONLINE_LIST2_PKG", **line 17**
>
> nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open
>   ORA-06512: at " PACKAGE ", **line 3**
>   ORA-06512: at " PACKAGE \, **line 17**, "providerErrorMessage":"CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL

So we opened up the package and the checked the cursor and the line number where the error is being thrown from.

```
1.     CURSOR c_t_num (trx_num_tran.trx_number%TYPE)
2.     IS
3.        SELECT interface_header_attribute1**
4.          FROM ra_customer_trx_all
5.         WHERE trx_number = trx_num;
6.           OPEN c_t_num (trx_list_rec.trx_number);
7.  
8.           FETCH c_t_num
9.            INTO t_rf_trx_number;
10. 
11.          IF c_t_num%NOTFOUND
12.          THEN
13.             t_rf_trx_number := NULL;
14.          END IF;
15. 
16.          CLOSE c_t_num;
17. OPEN c_t_num (p_trx_num);
18. 
19.       FETCH c_t_num
20.        INTO t_trx_number;
21. 
22.       IF c_t_num%NOTFOUND
23.       THEN
24.          t_trx_number := NULL;
25.       END IF;
26. 
27.       CLOSE c_t_num;
28. 

29. OPEN c_t_num (v_trx_num);
30. 
31.       FETCH c_t_num
32.        INTO t_trx_num_ritel;
33. 
34.       CLOSE c_t_num;
35. 
36.       RETURN (t_trx_num_ritel);
37.    END get_trx_number;
```

Now, the cursor is being opened at line numbers 6,17 and 29. But the exception always shows line number 3 (the select of the cursor definition) and line number 17.

Is this is an implicit type cursor (and this a legacy code) we think perhaps exception handling is the issue?

We have exception handling for no data found but none for TOO_MANY_ROWS , in all the blocks including when we open the cursor from line 17.

Can anyone help/suggest on this issue?

Comment: The code doesn't look valid. A cursor like this would need to be declared in the `declare` section, i.e. between `function get_trx_number ... is` and `begin`. You can't just go from `cursor c_t_num is...` to `open c_t_num`. Also I don't see any exception handling, or anywhere that `no_data_found` or `too_many_rows` could occur.

Comment: While the code you've posted doesn't look complete, It is even hard for us to debug in a situation you have that it "happens only sometimes (once in a week or so)" . It is your database and environment  setup and you know best as to what could be the reason for such occurrence. One way is to add more information from the code into logs and try to recreate that mysterious scenario in a test setup. I doubt if anybody could help you more on this, unless you give more clue as to what could be the problem.

Comment: Hi - I have only pasted a snippet, I can't paste the whole code, The declare section does contain no_data_found exception handling but I can not see any for too_many_rows. I spoke to the BA and apparently the expected behavior is to get/retrieve 1 row only. We suspect some functional changes are breaking this and the 1-1 mapping between the cursor and the matching rows is broken

Answer (score 0):

Before opening your cursor(in this example named `c_main_script_1`) do this:

```
if c_main_script_1%isopen then
    close c_main_script_1;
end if;
```

-Leah Jarvis